# Symfony form collection not saving reference

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have entity which has multiple Photos:

```
/**
 * related images
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Photo", mappedBy="entity",cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"uploaded_at" = "ASC"})
 */
private $photos;
```

Photos have ManyToOne relation with entity

```
    /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\AppBundle\Entity\Entity", inversedBy="photos")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="entity_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
private $entity;
```

all setters and getter are set I'm foliving symfony collection documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html

FormType:

```
             ->add('photos', 'collection', array(
             'type' => new PhotoFormType(),
             'allow_add' => true,
             'by_reference' => false,
             'allow_delete' => true,
             'prototype' => true

         ))
```

PhotoType:

```
        $builder
        ->add('title', null, ['label' => 'front.photo.title', 'required' => true])
        ->add('image', 'file', array('required' => false))
    ;
```

For upload I'm using vichUploadableBundle, Images are save just fine, but entity_id is not save and has null. I don't know what I did miss here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've went to this also. I think the main problem is that even the main entity has cascade={"persist"} , the child entites do not get the ID when you are creating a new entry.
So what I did, that is kind of a hack, but works fine is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096352/onetomany-relationship-not-persisting-along-with-new-entities).

```
// $em->persist($entity);  After persisting entity:
foreach ($entity->getPhotos() as $photo) {
    $photo->setEntity($entity);
}
```

Basically persisting the ID in the childs after their father is created.

But on another point, at least how I understand Doctrine, please correct me if I'm wrong. Try to add an orphanRemoval / fetch additional properties:

FATHER Entity has:

```php
 /**
  * Related images.
  * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Photo", mappedBy="entity", cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval=true, fetch="EAGER")
  * @ORM\OrderBy({"uploaded_at" = "ASC"})
  */

  private $photos;
```

Comment: I'm guessing you could probably just do this in an add method as well instead of iterating through all of them. This really seems like something Doctrine should be handling though.

Answer (score 6):

Following would be best solution on this issue so far investigate or research with symfony form component.

FormType:

```
     ->add("photos",'collection', array(
            'type' => new PhotoFormType(),
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'by_reference' => false
))
```

Entity class

```
public function addPhoto(Photo $photo)
{
    $photo->setEntity($this);
    $this->photos->add($photo);        
}

public function removePhoto(Photo $photo)
{
    $this->photos->removeElement($photo);
}
```

Best practice is not to use loop to bind reference entity manually . Remember by_reference must be false. like 'by_reference' => false.

Comment: Thanks, the `by_reference => false` line did the trick for me!

Comment: Cleanest solution available, no need to iterate over each element on the controller.

Comment: remember you might need to add a `$photo->setEntity(null)` in the entity class method removePhoto, to remove photos when edit, and `orphanRemoval=true` in the photo annotation in the entity class

Answer (score 4):

Run into the same issue, still I remember there is better solution.

You need to specify add and remove functions in the entity with collection.

```
class Entity
{
    // ...

    public function addPhoto(Photo $photo)
    {
        $this->photos->add($photo);
        $photo->setEntity($this);
    }

    public function removePhoto(Photo $photo)
    {
        $this->photos->removeElement($photo);
    }
}
```

So in such a case you wouldn't need a loop in the controller. 
Also if

> orphanRemoval=true

is set, no problems with delete.

Comment: +1 For the `orphanRemoval=true` trick, I have an inverse relation and had problems deleting elements. With this I don't to iterate over each element and remove it inside the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Photo Entity is persisted so I add to controller handler to set for every photo Entity. Don't know if it's right solution but it's working.

```
                /** @var Photo $photo */
                foreach ($entity->getPhotos() as $photo){
                    $photo->setEntity($entity);
                    $em->persist($photo);
                }
```

Comment: Looks good, but I wouldn't do a persist on every loop, just a : $em->flush() after the foreach :)